# how to overcome duplicate results caused by datatype property

Tags: sparql

I am using a java WS to query a repository. I cannot change data in this repository.
When I query anything, if any of the variables have "datatype" property I get duplicate results.

Is there a way to remove the duplicates with only using query?

Thanks for your help. Problem example is as follows,

My fixed namespaces

```
public static final String PREFIX = "prefix kb: <http://protege.stanford.edu/kb#>\n" +      
                                    "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                                    "prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>\n" +
                                    "prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n" +         
                                    "prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>\n";
```

My query string

```
String query = "SELECT DISTINCT ?name WHERE {" +
            "?unit a kb:Unit ; " +
            "kb:hasName ?name ;" +
            "} ORDER BY ?name ";
```

When I use this query I get duplicate values with "datatype" such as

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="name"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Hours</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Meters per Hour</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Meters per Hour</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Meters per Minute</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>PercentageCompleted</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Pieces per Hour</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Pieces per Hour</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Pieces per Minute</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Pieces per Minute</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Product parts</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>Products per Day</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Products per Day</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>SI Cubic Meter</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>€ per Hour</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>€ per Minute</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
    <result>
      <binding name="name">
        <literal>€ per Product</literal>
      </binding>
    </result>
  </results>
</sparql>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is similar to this

```
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select distinct ?name where {
  values ?name { "meters per hour"
                 "meters per hour"^^xsd:string }
}
```

```
---------------------------------
| name                          |
=================================
| "meters per hour"             |
| "meters per hour"^^xsd:string |
---------------------------------
```

Instead you should select distinct values of `str(?name)` (i.e., the string value of literal):

```
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select distinct (str(?name) as ?sname) where {
  values ?name { "meters per hour"
                 "meters per hour"^^xsd:string }
}
```

```
---------------------
| sname             |
=====================
| "meters per hour" |
---------------------
```

Note that in the future, this probably won't be so much an issue.  RDF 1.1 will make all literals have a datatype, and what were formerly simple literals (e.g., `"meters per hour"`) will have datatype `xsd:string` (e.g., `"meters per hour"^^xsd:string`).